# Помогите упростить код кнопки сохранения

Tags: c#

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Имеется база данных. На форме компонент dataGridViev.
При заполнении данных: ряд, место, имя заказчика и нажатии "Изменить заказ"
идет сохранение в БД. Помогите упростить код кнопки сохранения. Буду весьма благодарен.

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Control c in panel1.Controls)            
    {
        foreach (Binding b in c.DataBindings)
        {
            b.WriteValue();
        }
    }         
    this.saveChanges();
}
```

Comment: В каком плане вы хотите сделать его проще?

Comment: @Anamnian не хочу использовать foreach, можно как-то без него?

Comment: можно без него, но код проще вряд ли станет

Comment: пускай. не хочу использовать foreach, как лучше переделать?

Comment: Как я понял, этот код из текстбоксов заносит данные в привязанные сущности. Т. к. текстбоксов всего три, можно просто написать три строки кода, напрямую присваивающие эти значения.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov верно, только если бы я знал, как правильно сделать. переделать. Я переделывал, но получилось весьма не корректно.

Comment: подскажет кто?.

Comment: да, код конечно усложнился... ухх, всем вас спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Без foreach (хотя под капотом он и есть) но при этом усложнив код и добавив немного лишнего

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    panel1.Controls.OfType<Control>()
        .SelectMany(x => x.DataBindings.OfType<Binding>())
        .Select(b => { b.WriteValue(); return b; }).ToArray();
    this.saveChanges();
}
```

Код только для ознакомления, не рекомендую его в прод пускать

Поясню, что тут происходит:

1. `panel1.Controls.OfType<Control>()` - получаем список контролов из панели в виде перечисления контролов. что позволяет делать следующие вызовы Linq
2. `.SelectMany(x => x.DataBindings.OfType<Binding>())` - из списка контролов из п. 1) получаем набор биндингов всех контролов в виде перечисления. То есть было - набор контролов. Стало - надор биндингов.
3. `.Select(b => { b.WriteValue(); return b; })` - вызываем `b.WriteValue()` для каждого из биндингов. Return нужен так как лямбда долдна что то возвращать
4. `.ToArray()` - это запускает всю логику из предыдущих пунктов в работу, то есть материализует коллекцию. Именно в этом вызове по сути где то внутри отработает foreach

Comment: не могли бы Вы вкратце дать описание. Хочу разобраться... Спасибо Вам огромное!

Comment: @noob0 обновил ответ

Comment: В качестве наркомании можно заменить на `return 0;` и потом `Sum();`, чтобы не создавать лишний массив. Хотя, семантически правильнее было бы написать `ToList().ForEach(...);`

Comment: @АндрейNOP правильней было бы вообще этот код не писать и сделать все через 2 цикла :)

Comment: @tym32167, ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯